# How do I connect Dreamweaver to a MySQL database on 1and1?

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

I am hosting a site on **1and1**, and having trouble connecting to a `MySQL database`.
I am very new to `MySQL` and `PHP`, so I'm not sure I did this right.

- Under my domain,

  - choose Web Space>MySQL Administration
  - (get taken to PHPMyAdmin)
- New Database
- Once DB has finished setup,

  - use "host", "username" and "password" given by 1and1 to connect Dreamweaver.

I tried doing this, but `Dreamweaver` gives me an "`Unknown error`", which doesn't help at all, as it doesn't even give an error *code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty common on shared hosting to allow db connections *only from* apps running on their servers. Connections from other clients are blocked/rejected.

If you are able to connect your Dreamweaver to a *local* (on your machine) MySQL server, then it's probably the case that 1and1 is blocking your remote access.

Comment: That seems incredibly impractical. I read that you can get around it using SSH tunnelling; I'm not entirely sure how, though.

Answer (score 1):

1and1 do not permit external connections to the databases

Answer (score -2):

You should still be fine to connect with dreamweaver. That error you get is usually because the publishing URL (usually the same as default www.domainnamehere.com) hasn't been configured in DW under the Testing Server section yet.